# How do you clear a textarea in a Phoenix LiveView form?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I have a Phoenix LiveView with a form that is not backed by a data layer, like so:

```
<%= f = form_for :post, "#", [phx_submit: :create_post %>
  <%= textarea f, :message, placeholder: "Say something:" %>
  <%= hidden_input f, :user_id, value: @current_user.account_id %>
  <%= submit "Post" %>
</form>
```

I can't back the form with a changeset because I am not using Ecto. After submitting the form, the submission is processed just fine, but the form `textarea` is not cleared. How can I clear inputs without resorting to Javascript?

If I can't do it without Javascript, how can I do it *with* Javascript, but *without* bypassing the LiveView `phx-submit` mechanisms?

**Some additional troubleshooting information:**

Here is my event handler:

```
def handle_event("create_post", %{"post" => post_params}, socket) do
  thread_id = socket.assigns.thread.id
  user_id = post_params["user_id"]
  posts = Forums.append_post!(thread_id, user_id, post_params)
  UdsWeb.Endpoint.broadcast_from(self(), build_topic(thread_id), "new_post", %{posts: posts})
  {:noreply, assign(socket, :posts, posts)}
end
```

I've tried several different approaches to fix the problem, mostly involving variations of data structures backing the form.

- I've tried backing the form with a map. This doesn't work because forms must be backed with structures that implement the `Phoenix.HTML.FormData` protocol, and Phoenix only implements this for `Plug.Conn` and `Atom`
- I've tried using a struct, but this doesn't work for the same reason as maps
- I don't have a `Conn` to use in my form, because this is a LiveView, but I could create a `Conn` in the LiveView controller, so I did. I backed the form with it and passed a new instance through in the event handler for post creation. This did not solve the problem.
- Finally, I changed the `textarea` to a `text_input`, and this input cleared immediately on submission of the form. So it seems the problem is specific to the `textarea` element. I'm not sure whether or not this is a bug with Phoenix.

Comment: I believe in your response handler you should explicitly create the new `Post` object.

Comment: I believe there are no objects.

Answer (score 2):

As Aleksei said in his comment: You have to pass a new `Post` struct from your controller to your view. For example like this:

```
def handle_event("create_post", post, socket) do
    # Here do what you want with the data from the "post" parameter

    {:noreply, assign(socket, :post, %Post{})}   
end
```

Comment: But I don't have any `Post` struct defined. After reading your answer, I tried passing an empty map instead of a `%Post{}`, but that didn't work either. Shouldn't a map be equivalent to a struct?

Comment: I just tried defining a `Post` struct too, and I passed it as you demonstrated in your answer, but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Even it behaves like a SPA it is not a SPA, so you still need to use the backend router and redirect it back to the `index` page. Your form is on the `index` page but the resource is not the `post's index` page, it is `post/new`.

So, you need to use `push_redirect` (not `redirect`):

```
|> push_redirect(to: UdsWeb.post_index_path(socket, :index))
```

```
def handle_event("create_post", %{"post" => post_params}, socket) do
  thread_id = socket.assigns.thread.id
  user_id = post_params["user_id"]
  posts = Forums.append_post!(thread_id, user_id, post_params)
  UdsWeb.Endpoint.broadcast_from(self(), build_topic(thread_id), "new_post", %{posts: posts})
  {:noreply,
   socket
   |> push_redirect(to: UdsWeb.post_index_path(socket, :index))}
end
```

Hex: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.html#push_redirect/2